# Open files located in the ACCDocs

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

I've developed a plugin project in Visual Studio with RevitAPI to open batch Revit files to export data. I can add many files which are on the networks and the plugin automatically opens all the files. Is it possible to open files that are in the ACC Docs cloud?

I know I can open AccDocs which were be already downloaded with searching in collaboration cache folder, but how to open files which are not yet downloaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned the `collaboration cache` folder, I suppose your Revit model is the [Revit Cloud Worksharing model](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/About-BIM360/files/about-bim-360-design/About-BIM360-about-bim-360-design-about-revit-cloud-worksharing-html-html.html) (a.k.a C4R model, model of Autodesk Collaboration for Revit).

If so, we can call APS Data Management to obtain the `projectGuid` and `modelGuid` in the model's version tip like below.

```json
{  
   "type":"versions",
   "id":"urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.abcd1234?version=1",
   "attributes":{  
      "name":"fileName.rvt",
      "displayName":"fileName.rvt",
      ...
      "mimeType":"application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
      "storageSize":123456,
      "fileType":"rvt",
      "extension":{  
         "type":"versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel",
         ....
         "data":{  
            ...
            "projectGuid":"48da72af-3aa6-4b76-866b-c11bb3d53883",
            ....
            "modelGuid":"e666fa30-9808-42f4-a05b-8cb8da576fe9",
            ....
         }
      }
   },
   ....
}
```

Afterward, open the C4R model using Revit API like below:

```cs
var region = ModelPathUtils.CloudRegionUS; //!<<< depends on where your BIM360/ACC account is based, US or EU.
var projectGuid = new Guid("48da72af-3aa6-4b76-866b-c11bb3d53883");
var modelGuid = new Guid("e666fa30-9808-42f4-a05b-8cb8da576fe9");

var modelPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath( region, projectGuid, modelGuid ); //!<<< For Revit 2023 and newer.
//var modelPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath( projectGuid, modelGuid ); //!<<< For Revit 2019 ~ 2022

var openOptions = new OpenOptions();
app.OpenAndActivateDocument( modelPath, openOptions ); //!<<< on desktop
// app.OpenDocumentFile( modelPath, openOptions ); //!<<< on Design Automation for Revit or don't want to activate the model on Revit desktop.
```

References:

- https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-bim-360-design-models-revit
- https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/04/revit-2021-cloud-model-api.html#4.4
- https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2023/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Application_and_Document_CloudFiles_html

Comment: Hi @Eason Kang
Many thx in taking time to answer me!
I realy appreciate!
Last question, I must get APS Data Management package in VisualStudio isn't it?

Comment: The client SDK for APS Data management API can be found on Nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge). We haven't rebranded it from Forge to APS yet. And you can find the tutorial here: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/data#server-endpoints

Comment: Hi @EasonKang,Thx for answering. Hop I'll be able to manager it in C#!

Comment: Awesome! Happy to hear it works on your side now.

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer. I shared it on the blog: [Opening a Model in ACC Docs](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2023/03/lookup-ideas-jigs-and-acc-docs-access.html#4).